# Firestore data doesn't show up in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to put my firestore data within a recyclerview in Android. The app comes up with no errors, however no data shows up.

```
public class Diseaselist extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private FirebaseFirestore mDatabaseRef;

    private Query mChartsQuery;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Upload, ProductViewHolder> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diseaselist);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.goodmeme);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String useruid = currentUser.getUid();


        Query query = rootRef.collection("users").document(useruid).collection("diagnoses")
                .orderBy("disease", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Upload> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Upload>()
                    .setQuery(query, Upload.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Upload, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Upload productModel) {
                holder.setProductName(productModel.getDisease());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
               android.view.View views = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_diseaselist, parent, false);
                return new ProductViewHolder(views);

            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
    private class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private android.view.View view;

        ProductViewHolder(android.view.View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }

        void setProductName(final String productName) {
            CardView cview =view.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.texty);
            textView.setText(productName);
            cview.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"

    tools:context=".Diseaselist"
    tools:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="30sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/goodmeme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKWui.png) [Firestore Structure Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7k8.png)

Upload Class code:

```
package com.Provendor.Provendor;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Upload implements Parcelable {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mdisease;
    private String mdate;
    private float mconfidence;
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeFloat(mconfidence);
        out.writeString(mName);
        out.writeString(mImageUrl);
        out.writeString(mdisease);
        out.writeString(mdate);
    }

    // this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Upload> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Upload>() {
        public Upload createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Upload(in);
        }

        public Upload[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Upload[size];
        }
    };

    // example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
    private Upload(Parcel in) {
        mconfidence = in.readInt();
        mName  = in.readString();
        mImageUrl  = in.readString();
        mdisease = in.readString();
        mdate = in.readString();

    }

    public Upload() {
        mName= ""; //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl, String disease, float confidence) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }
        mdisease=disease;
        mdate=java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
        mconfidence=confidence;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
    public String getDisease() {
        return mdisease;
    }
    public float getConfidence() {
        return mconfidence;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return mdate;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }
    public void setdate() {
        mdate=java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
    public void setDisease(String disease) {
        mdisease = disease;
    }
    public void setConfidence(float confidence) {
        mconfidence = confidence;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to produce a list of diseases based on the firestore collection, however the recyclerview is left empty. When attached to debug, no errors come up! Thanks for looking this over!

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your `Upload` class.

Comment: Thanks alex, i just updated the post to include this information

Comment: Please add also a screenshot with the content of one document (155 ... 940).

Comment: The second screenshot includes the content of a document https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7k8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting anything from the database because the name of your fields inside the `Upload` class are different than the name of the fields that exist in the database. Both should match. To solve this, you either change all the name of your fields inside your `Upload` class to match the properties that exist in the database or your can use annotations. Because I see that you are using private fields and public getters, you should use the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation only in front of the getter, for instance your `getName()` getter should look like this:

```
@PropertyName("name")
public String getName() {
    return mName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response!